# 3ware: Replace failed disk with Spare

Tags: raid, 3ware

I have a 3ware RAID controller running a RAID-10.

I have a disk that currently has a `SMART-FAILURE`.  I've ran a `/c0 rescan` and the Status will change to OK then back to `SMART-FAILURE`

```
> /c0 show

Unit  UnitType  Status         %RCmpl  %V/I/M  Stripe  Size(GB)  Cache  AVrfy
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
u0    RAID-1    OK             -       -       -       931.312   RiW    OFF
u1    RAID-10   OK             -       -       256K    3725.25   RiW    OFF
u3    SPARE     OK             -       -       -       931.505   -      OFF

VPort Status         Unit Size      Type  Phy Encl-Slot    Model
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
p0    OK             u0   931.51 GB SATA  0   -            ST1000DM005 HD103SJ
p1    OK             u0   931.51 GB SATA  1   -            ST1000DM005 HD103SJ
p3    OK             u1   931.51 GB SATA  3   -            ST1000DM005 HD103SJ
p4    OK             u1   931.51 GB SATA  4   -            ST1000DM005 HD103SJ
p5    OK             u1   931.51 GB SATA  5   -            ST1000DM005 HD103SJ
p6    OK             u1   931.51 GB SATA  6   -            ST1000DM005 HD103SJ
p7    OK             u1   931.51 GB SATA  7   -            ST1000DM005 HD103SJ
p8    SMART-FAILURE  u1   931.51 GB SATA  8   -            ST1000DM005 HD103SJ
p9    OK             u1   931.51 GB SATA  9   -            ST1000DM005 HD103SJ
p10   OK             u1   931.51 GB SATA  10  -            ST1000DM005 HD103SJ
p11   OK             u3   931.51 GB SATA  11  -            ST1000DM005 HD103SJ
```

I've done some research on how to replace a disk but can't find any documentation that I've found doesn't go into how to replace the disk with a spare unit.

How do I replace the p8 disk with the u3 unit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the p8 disk and the u3 unit started rebuilding itself. It happens automatically.